# Deploy Strapi Foodadvisor with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, next.js, minikube, strapi

I'm trying to deploy the [FoodAdvisor](https://github.com/strapi/foodadvisor) app on a local cluster running minikube. The frontend is written in Next.JS. For the most part I have gotten it to work, however, the backend needs the URL of the frontend and vice versa. The URL of the backend is used in the frontend as first to fetch the contents and load the UI and then in links to download media. As such, the URL is used both internally by the NExt.JS server as well as the browser.

I have used two services to expose the backend and frontend.

The backend deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foodadvisor-backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foodadvisor
      component: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foodadvisor
        component: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: foodadvisor-api
        image: heraldofsolace/foodadvisor-api
```

The frontend deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: foodadvisor-frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: foodadvisor
      component: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: foodadvisor
        component: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: foodadvisor-client
        image: heraldofsolace/foodadvisor-client
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
```

The backend service file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foodadvisor-api
spec:
  selector:
    app: foodadvisor
    component: backend
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 1337
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The frontend service file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foodadvisor-client
spec:
  selector:
    app: foodadvisor
    component: frontend
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

With this setup, I set the backend URL to `http://foodadvisor-api`. Now the frontend loads, but I get 404 errors in the console because the browser is now trying to download media from `http://foodadvisor-api`.

Comment: Have you checked this [GKE document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) already? I think it will help you a lot.

Comment: If you don't need to expose your backend externally, you can use a simple `ClusterIP` (default service type). You don't really need to use `LoadBalancer` type in this scenario.